# how to get data in ruby controller and post it back to html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, http, curl

I want to call a ruby controller `app_v1` through `curl` command :

`curl --verbose --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"content":"meta data"}' http://localhost:7000/app_v1/view`

`routes` file has :

```
resources :app_v1 do 
  collection do 
    get :view
  end
end
```

But I am facing error stating routing error but when i am not sending any data i.e. `curl http://localhost:7000/app_v1/view`  then the data which i want to display is been rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have an issue with controller name I guess not Sure. But this solution work for me

**1:** Create controller `app/controllers/app_v1_controller.rb`

**2:**

```
class AppV1Controller < ApplicationController
  def view
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

**3:**

```
     resources :app_v1 do
        collection do
          get :view
        end
      end
```

`curl http://localhost:3000/app_v1/view`

### Return

---

> [{"id":1,"first_name":"vinay","last_name":"gupta","email":"vgvinay2@gmail.com","address":"bangamane
>   tech paerkjkm"}]

---

**`curl --verbose --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-type: application/json" --request GET --data '{"content":"meta data"}' http://localhost:3000/app_v1/view`**

### Return

---

> json" --request GET --data '{"content":"meta data"}'
>   http://localhost:3000/app_v1/view
>   * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
>   *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
>   * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
>
> > GET /app_v1/view HTTP/1.1
> >     User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> >     Host: localhost:3000
> >     Accept: application/json
> >     Content-type: application/json
> >     Content-Length: 23
> >
> > - upload completely sent off: 23 out of 23 bytes < HTTP/1.1 200 OK  < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN < X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block <
> >       X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff < Content-Type: application/json;
> >       charset=utf-8 < Etag: W/"01885a844e824dae54d6e0556099efe8" <
> >       Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate < X-Request-Id:
> >       82e9634c-e2ef-489d-bc43-b2f4e8aacf4c < X-Runtime: 0.007763
> > - Server WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.1/2014-02-24) is not blacklisted < Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.1/2014-02-24) < Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015
> >       13:54:34 GMT < Content-Length: 116 < Connection: Keep-Alive <
> > - Connection #0 to host localhost left intact [{"id":1,"first_name":"vinay","last_name":"gupta","email":"vgvinay2@gmail.com","address":"bangamane
> >       tech paerkjkm"}]

---

Hope this help You !!!

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it because you do `POST` request in the first case whereas your routes files only match a `GET` request.
Simple curl command without `--request POST` do a `GET` request by default.

You have to change your `routes`file to match a `POST` request

```
resources :app_v1 do 
  collection do 
    post :view
  end
end
```